# XPathSelectElement always return null

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

```
string xml = @"<vehicle>   <cars>     <car>tet</car>    </cars> </vehicle>";
XElement x = XElement.Parse(xml);
var node = x.XPathSelectElement("//vehicle/cars");
```

why is the node always null?

Answer (score -1):

XPath should be

```
var node = x.XPathSelectElement("cars");
```

### OUTPUT:

```
<cars>
  <car>tet</car>
</cars>
```

Comment: This also returns null

Comment: @HennovanRensburg: Use cars